# Efficient metrics evaluation in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and want to efficiently evaluate among others F1 during my Training and my Validation Loop.

So far, my approach was to calculate the predictions on GPU, then push them to CPU and append them to a vector for both Training and Validation. After Training and Validation, I would evaluate both for each epoch using sklearn. However, profiling my code it showed, that pushing to cpu is quite a bottleneck.

```py
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    model.train()
    avg_loss = 0
    avg_val_loss = 0
    train_pred = np.array([])
    val_pred = np.array([])
    # Training loop (transpose X_batch to fit pretrained (features, samples) style)
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        scores = model(X_batch)
        y_pred = F.softmax(scores, dim=1)
        train_pred = np.append(train_pred, self.get_vector(y_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()))

        loss = loss_fn(scores, self.get_vector(y_batch))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        avg_loss += loss.item() / len(train_loader)

    model.eval()
    # Validation loop
    for X_batch, y_batch in val_loader:
        with torch.no_grad():
            scores = model(X_batch)
            y_pred = F.softmax(scores, dim=1)
            val_pred = np.append(val_pred, self.get_vector(y_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()))
            loss = loss_fn(scores, self.get_vector(y_batch))
            avg_val_loss += loss.item() / len(val_loader)

    # Model Checkpoint for best validation f1
    val_f1 = self.calculate_metrics(train_targets[val_index], val_pred, f1_only=True)
    if val_f1 > best_val_f1:
        prev_best_val_f1 = best_val_f1
        best_val_f1 = val_f1
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), self.PATHS['xlm'])
        evaluated_epoch = epoch

    # Calc the metrics
    self.save_metrics(train_targets[train_index], train_pred, avg_loss, 'train')
    self.save_metrics(train_targets[val_index], val_pred, avg_val_loss, 'val')
```

I am certain there is a more efficient way to 
a) store the predictions without having to push them to cpu each batch. b) calculate the metrics on GPU directly?

As I am new to PyTorch, I am very grateful for any hints and feedback :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can compute the F-score yourself in pytorch. The F1-score is defined for single-class (true/false) classification only. The only thing you need is to aggregating the number of:

- Count of the class in the ground truth target data;
- Count of the class in the predictions;
- Count how many times the class was correctly predicted.

Let's assume you want to compute F1 score for the class with index `0` in your softmax. In every batch, you can do:

```py
predicted_classes = torch.argmax(y_pred, dim=1) == 0
target_classes = self.get_vector(y_batch)
target_true += torch.sum(target_classes == 0).float()
predicted_true += torch.sum(predicted_classes).float()
correct_true += torch.sum(
    predicted_classes == target_classes * predicted_classes == 0).float()
```

When all batches are processed:

```py
recall = correct_true / target_true
precision = correct_true / predicted_true
f1_score = 2 * precission * recall / (precision + recall)
```

Don't forget to take care of cases when precision and recall are zero and when then desired class was not predicted at all.

Comment: "The F1-score is defined for single-class (true/false) classification only", not true chk https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html, param `average`.

Comment: (Semi)-related to this: when calculating the metrics, is there a reason one would want to do it on the CPU and not GPU? This is how they do it in [Andrew Ng's tutorial](https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/handsigns/) (move to CPU). I also asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65179954/4031135) about this and I would appreciate any insights you can provide.