# Should a data batch be moved to CPU and converted (from torch Tensor) to a numpy array when doing evaluation w.r.t. a metric during the training?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am going through [Andrew Ng’s tutorial from the CS230 Stanford course](https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/handsigns/), and in [every epoch of the training](https://github.com/cs230-stanford/cs230-code-examples/blob/master/pytorch/vision/train.py#L120), evaluation is performed by calculating the metrics.

But before calculating the metrics, they are sending the batches to CPU and converting them to numpy arrays ([code here](https://github.com/cs230-stanford/cs230-code-examples/blob/master/pytorch/vision/evaluate.py#L55)).

```
# extract data from torch Variable, move to cpu, convert to numpy arrays
output_batch = output_batch.data.cpu().numpy()
labels_batch = labels_batch.data.cpu().numpy()

# compute all metrics on this batch
summary_batch = {metric: metrics[metric](output_batch, labels_batch) for metric in metrics}
```

My question is: why do they do that? Why don’t they just calculate the metrics (which is done [here](https://github.com/cs230-stanford/cs230-code-examples/blob/master/pytorch/vision/model/net.py#L105)) on GPU using torch methods (e.g. `torch.sum` as opposed to `np.sum`)?

I would think that GPU to CPU transfers would slow things down, so there should be a very good reason for doing them?

I am new to PyTorch so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

**Correct me if I'm wrong**. Sending back the data to the CPU allows to reduce the GPU load even though memory is replaced when entering the following loop cycle. Futhermore, I believe converting to `numpy` has the advantage of freeing memory since you are detaching your data from the calculation graph. You end up manipulating `labels_batch.cpu().numpy()` a *fixed* array vs `labels_batch` a tensor attached to the entire network through linked `backward_fn` callbacks.

Comment: I thought that transferring the data from GPU to CPU would actually slow things down (e.g. in [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/7-tips-for-squeezing-maximum-performance-from-pytorch-ca4a40951259) by PyTorch Lightning creator, he is saying that GPU --> CPU transfers should be avoided because they are "really bad for performance").

Comment: Thank you for the article, I honestly didn't about that. So maybe it's just better to do those accuracy calculations on GPU. I hope someone else will give his/her point of view here!